# Error: Could not resolve class ... named for instantiation when creating objects in HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to understand how to create DTO objects in Hibernate. I've uploaded the minimal code for an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/maeln0r/hibernate_test).

I have code that, I believe, should receive a List<Linked> based on the selection from an HQL select query, but when executing it, I receive an error 'org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve class 'ru.maelnor.entity.Linked' named for instantiation'.

```java
List<Linked> linkedPurchases = session.createQuery(
    "select new ru.maelnor.entity.Linked(c.id, s.id) " +
    "from Purchase pl " +
    "join Good c on pl.goodName = c.name " +
    "join User s on pl.userName = s.name", Linked.class)
        .getResultList();
```

I'm learning Hibernate and am not completely confident in the correctness of my approach, which is based on my experience with other ORMs. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it looks like a hibernate bug.

In first we need to add class via `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Linked.class);`

```java
    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Linked.class);
        configuration.configure();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }
```

After that the previously specified query will work correctly.

It looks like a bug that adding the same class via hibernate.cfg.xml does not work as expected.